# how to import a webpack submodule?

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, require

in my setup, I have a react component as part of an npm package called 'share-sheet'. It's managed by webpack as such:

**webpack.config.js**

```
...
output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
},
entry: path.join(__dirname, 'src/index')
...
```

**package.json**

```
...
"main": "dist/bundle.js",
...
```

**index.js**

```
import FancyButton from 'components/FancyButton'
import FancyHellicopter from 'components/FancyHellicopter'

console.log(`my fancy button component: ${FancyButton}`)

module.exports = { FancyButton, FancyHellicopter }
```

On the other hand I have a webapp, which also uses webpack, which is setup as such:

**app.js**

```
import _ from 'lodash'
import sharesheet from 'share-sheet'
console.log(_) // outputs the lodash object correctly.
console.log(sharesheet) // outputs empty object.
console.log(sharesheet.FancyButton) // outputs undefined.
```

Once I run the app.js, the lines inside the share-sheet's `index.js` get printed correctly in the console, but once inside the app.js itself, the sharesheet is an empty object. So somehow the object exported at `module.exports` doesn't get returned once the share-sheet module is imported. what is wrong exactly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because webpack doesn't know the exporting strategy of 'share-sheet' package. Configuring `output.libraryTarget` to `commonjs2` should solve the problem.

**webpack.config.js**

```
...
output: {
  path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist'),
  filename: 'bundle.js',
  libraryTarget: 'commonjs2' // <----------
},
entry: path.join(__dirname, 'src/index')
...
```

You can find more informations about building library with webpack in [here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/).